# StyleCop SA1638

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, stylecop

I am using StyleCop in VS2008. I get this error:

**SA1638: The file attribute in the file header's copyright tag must contain the name of the file.**

Here is my header.

```
// <copyright file="AssemblyInfo.cs" company="company">
// Copyright (c) company. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
// <author>me</author>
// <email>me@me.com</email>
// <date>2010-03-04</date>
// <summary>blah blah.</summary>
```

I suspect the problem is that my AssemblyInfo.cs is located inside the Properties folder. Any clues to how I can fix this warning without silencing StyleCop?

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: Nope. No fix. I had to suppress that warning.

Comment: That's very strange.  I can only assume you've found a bug in StyleCop then.  Answer updated!

Comment: Thanks, Task. I will post the reproducible sample later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the file in Solution Explorer, open the right-click Properties window, copy the text in the "File Name" area, paste that into the header.

The Properties directory shouldn't matter, I'd assume you've got a typo in there somewhere.

Addition:
If that doesn't work, then to fix it you'll have to take it to the next level.
Copy the whole project to a new solution, re-scan with StyleCop.
Delete all unrelated files, re-scan with StyleCop.
Delete all code in the problem file except the header, re-scan with StyleCop.
If the problem disappears somewhere along the way, that would be really weird.
If the problem doesn't disappear, then you've got a reproducible sample!

Zip up that sample and attach it to a new work item here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis/WorkItem/List.aspx

Given some time there will likely be a new release to fix the bug.  8 )

Answer (score 3):

I have the following for an AssemblyInfo.cs file in the Properties folder:

```
// <copyright file="AssemblyInfo.cs" company="company">
// product
// Copyright (c) 2004-2010
// by company ( http://www.example.com )
// </copyright>
```

And it doesn't have any problems with that.  Are you sure that you the file name is correct (maybe casing is off?) and that you don't have any invalid XML (an ampersand in your company name, perhaps)?

Answer (score 2):

*According to StyleCop Documentation, this is how you would handle `AssemblyInfo.cs` nowadays:*

A file that is completely auto-generated by a tool, and which should not be checked or enforced by StyleCop, can include an “auto-generated” header rather than the standard file header. This will cause StyleCop to ignore the file. This type of header should never be placed on top of a manually written code file.

```
// <auto-generated />
namespace Sample.Something
{
    // The contents of this file are completely auto-generated by a tool.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the file name is different from the class name inside that file. Make the file name and class name the same will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

most probably issue is your File name and Class name is different.
If you can update your class as partial then this error will not show from StyleCop.

Answer (score 0):

The filename and class should be same.

please use this after file header documentation.It will fix the issues.

```html
[module: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1649:FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchTypeName", Justification = "Reviewed.")]
```